# Extension or setting in Firefox to change the Downloads window into a tab?

Tags: macos, firefox, browser-addons, osx-leopard

Simple problem: I'd like the Downloads window to appear as a tab in Firefox.  I used to use [Downloads in Tab 0.0.6](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4526) but it doesn't seem to be compatible with Firefox 3.x.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Download Manager Tweak](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/256) does what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Forgive me if you're set on a tab-based download add-on, but I can't recommend [Download Statusbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/26) highly enough. If your goal was to eliminate the Downloads window, that extension is as unobtrusive as they get.